# password data type required to implement JOSSO single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, josso

I'm trying to implement Single Sign On using JOSSO.
My user credentials are stored in Users table with data type of password column is varbinary. Now can I implement JOSSO without altering my Users table?

Comment: How does this relate to jsf?

Comment: sorry. this is not related to JSF